# iOS: I need to get data from a bluetooth device continually in background/foreground service

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, background-service

I read this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks but I didn't get any specific result to be able to run a service.
In this service, the data of the device connected to Bluetooth is taken and stored in the database.

1. How to configure bluetooth?
2. How to configure background service tasks?